# ISNULL twice for the same column

Tags: sql-server, isnull

Is it possible to use ISNULL twice for the same column?

```
ISNULL(ISNULL(column, SELECT sum(column2) FROM table WHERE type = '1')), SELECT sum(column2) FROM table WHERE type = '2'))
```

Or should I be doing this in a different way with IF ELSE somehow? How would that look like?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Sorry, seems a different RDBMS

Comment: @user4035 Looks like SQL Server's `ISNULL()`, but I guess it may exist in other databases too.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Yes, it is SQL Server. In MySQL the corresponding operator is called IFNULL

Answer (score 3):

Look at the [`coalesce` operator](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/comparison-operators.html#function_coalesce).  Your query then becomes:

```
COALESCE(column, 
    (SELECT sum(column2) FROM table WHERE type = '1'), 
    (SELECT sum(column2) FROM table WHERE type = '2'))
```

It returns the first non-null result from its arguments.

Comment: In my case I only want to get a non-null value if the value is null. With COALESCE it will return the first non-value from its arguments. Have I misunderstood COALESCE or can it be written so that it will only take the first non-null value from arguments if the original value is null?

Comment: "can it be written so that it will only take the first non-null value from arguments if the original value is null?"  If the original value is null, it will take the first non-null value from its arguments.  If the original value is not null, it returns the original value.  I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, it is possible.

(The issue I see with the expression in the question is unbalanced parens; two extra closing parens)

The `ISNULL` function takes two arguments. Either (or both) of those arguments can be expressions, and an `ISNULL` function is an expression. So yes, you can nest ISNULL functions two, three, four, or more levels deep as you need.

A SELECT statement that returns a single row containing a single column can (usually) be used as an expression. And multiple SELECT statements (subqueries) within a query can reference the same table(s) and same column(s).

In many cases, when we see a query of this type, it points either to a model that isn't working well, or it points to looking at a different way of getting an equivalent result.

**EDIT**

As other answers have pointed out, the more portable, ANSI-standard compliant `COALESCE` function can be used to return an equivalent result.

These three expressions are equivalent:

```
ISNULL(ISNULL(a,b),c) 
ISNULL(a,ISNULL(b,c)) 
COALESCE(a,b,c)
```

which are also equivalent to these (unnecessarily redundant) expressions:

```
COALESCE(COALESCE(a,b),c)
COALESCE(a,(COALESCE(b,c))
```

Test case:

```
create table tst (id int, a int, b int, c int);
insert into tst values 
(1,NULL,NULL,NULL)
,(2,21,NULL,NULL)
,(3,NULL,32,NULL)
,(4,NULL,NULL,43)
,(5,51,52,NULL)
,(6,61,NULL,63)
,(7,NULL,72,73)
,(8,81,82,83);

-- SQL Server
SELECT ISNULL(ISNULL(a,b),c) AS t1 
     , ISNULL(a,ISNULL(b,c)) AS t2
     , COALESCE(a,b,c)       AS t3
  FROM tst
 ORDER BY id

-- MySQL
SELECT IFNULL(IFNULL(a,b),c) AS t1 
     , IFNULL(a,IFNULL(b,c)) AS t2
     , COALESCE(a,b,c)       AS t3
  FROM tst
 ORDER BY id

-- Oracle
SELECT NVL(NVL(a,b),c)       AS t1 
     , NVL(a,NVL(b,c))       AS t2
     , COALESCE(a,b,c)       AS t3
  FROM tst
 ORDER BY id
```

Comment: Do you recommend using ISNULL this way or do you mean that based on your experience this tends to not be working well?

Comment: @mediasurface: I think it's fine for you to use ISNULL. The expression in the question is fine (apart from the mismatched parens), as long as it's returning the resultset you need. As other answers have pointed out, you can accomplish the same result using the more portable ANSI-standard compliant `COALESCE` function.

Answer (score 0):

Try using COALESCE (if you are using SQL Server). http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190349.aspx

It will give you the first non-null value from a list of values.  Do you need more help structuring the SQL also?

Comment: In my case I only want to get a non-null value if the value is null. With COALESCE it will return the first non-value from its arguments. Have I misunderstood COALESCE or can it be written so that it will only take the first non-null value from arguments if the original value is null?

Comment: You are reading COALESCE correctly.  If you need to ensure you only get back rows where the result will be not null, you can handle this in your WHERE clause by checking for (Value1 IS NOT NULL OR Value2 IS NOT NULL OR etc).  This will ensure your results include only rows that will produce a non-null value.  But....you could also put the query you wrote inside another query (making it a sub-query) and specifying you only want to get back rows where the result of the COALESCE is not null.  I can explain this more if that does not make sense.